# Is there any function in vb.net as an alternative to magic methods __get() and __set() in php

Tags: vb.net, get, encapsulation, getter

PHP has magic methods like `__get()` and `__set()`. Is there any alternative for it in vb.net. Or is there any other tricks that can be done instead?

This was what i done in php

```
private $data = array();

public function __construct($arData) {
    $data['var1'] = 'value1';
    $data['var2'] = 'value2';
    $data['var3'] = 'value3';
}

public function __get($propertyName) {
    if(!array_key_exists($propertyName, $this->data))
        throw new Exception("Invalid property");
    else
        return $this->data[$propertyName];
}
```

Now i am able to access property that actually doesn't exist like `$obj->var1`, `$obj->var2` and `$obj->var3`

Can this be done in VB .Net?

Comment: Besides (writeonly|readonly) Property ?

Comment: Or do you need create property if it doesn't exist?

Comment: i want to create property that doesn't exist

Comment: They are really called magic methods (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)?!

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a private dictionary to keep Property Name/Values pairs. Something like:

```
Public Class myObj

    Private m_aProperties As Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Public Sub New()
        m_aProperties = New (Of String, String)
    End Sub

    Public Function __Get(i_sPropName As String) As String

        If m_aProperties.ContainsKey(i_sPropName) Then
            Return m_aProperties(i_sPropName)
        Else
            Return String.Empty
        End If

    End Function

    Public Sub __Set(i_sPropName As String, i_sPropValue As String)

        If m_aProperties.ContainsKey(i_sPropName) Then
            m_aProperties(i_sPropName) = i_sPropValue
        Else
            m_aProperties.Add(i_sPropName, i_sPropValue)
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

It would create a new entry in dictionary if the property doesn't exist. It will return an empty string if you attempt to return a non-existing property. Example of usage:

```
    Dim myObj1 As New myObj

    myObj1.__Set("aaa", "123")
    Dim s As String = myObj1.__Get("aaa")
```

This can be expanded to work for different data types, to handle non-existing properties differently etc. But the basic concept to create property at runtime is to keep it in a dictonary.

Comment: But what this dictionary does (by assuming that is what the OP wants, what is still not clear to me) is basically what you can do via reflection; which will be more or less as expensive as the dictionary you are proposing (without the hassle of the implementation).

Comment: That was ok but accessing variables via methods with params is much harder.Is there any way to access those in the same way as accessing variables (as done in php)?

Comment: Not with the "dot" notation ( myObj1.aaa ) no. Only via actual string property name

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Get`/`Set` or even nothing. Sample code:

```
Public Class testClass
    Private _val As String

    Public Property myProp1 As String
        Get
            Return _val
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _val = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property myProp2 As String
End Class
```

You can access these properties by doing:

```
Dim test As testClass = New testClass()
test.myProp1 = "val1"
test.myProp2 = "val2"
```

As you can see, `myProp1` has the `Get`/`Set` structure; my `myProp2` is declared like a variable. Practically speaking, both alternatives deliver the same.

UPDATE

You can emulate the PHP behaviour in your post via `System.Reflection`:

```
Public Function _get(propertyName As String, curInstance As testClass) As Object

    Dim curProp As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = curInstance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)
    Dim outVal As Object = Nothing
    If (curProp IsNot Nothing) Then
        outVal = curProp.GetValue(curInstance, Nothing)
    Else
        'NOT FOUND
    End If

    Return outVal
End Function

Public Sub _set(propertyName As String, curInstance As testClass, newVal As Object) 

    Dim curProp As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = curInstance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)
    If (curProp IsNot Nothing) Then
        curProp.SetValue(curInstance, newVal, Nothing)
    Else
        'NOT FOUND
    End If

End Sub
```

What can be called:

```
Dim outval As String = DirectCast(_get("myProp1", test), String)
_set("myProp2", test, "val3")
```

Comment: that was not what i meant.. what if i need to create a property that doesn't exist? i mean i should be able to access a lot of properties outside the class, but actually none should exist inside

Comment: @j126 just to make sure that there is no misunderstanding: the second code is outside testClass, for example in Class1. You can put all the variables in testClass (which might be even located in an external file, like a DLL) and the rest of the code in Class1. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @j126 After looking at Yuriy's answer, it is clear to me that what you want is not clear at all. Could you please add a descriptive enough example of what you are after in your description?

Comment: That was ok but accessing variables via methods with params is much harder. Now i understood that it is not possible to emulate the PHP behaviour exactly. what i meant was, to access the the data as variables like $obj->var1 in php or obj.var1 in vb.net while var1 actually doesn't exist

Comment: @j126 accessing inexistent variables is a concept whose point I am not sure about. In any case, this is not the way to learn a new programming language, mainly when they are so different as PHP and. NET. You should face your current problem or any future one you have with an approach on the lines of "what is the best way to get this behavior in. NET?". Any other would be inefficient and a bit pointless (languages are expected to be helpful, not the contrary).