# vb.net equivalent of php magic methods

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, polymorphism

I'm trying to create a dynamic object in vb.net, this would be simple using PHPas it has magic methods for getters, setters, and calling methods, but I need to do this in vb.net

In PHP:

```
<?php
    class foo {
        private $vars = array()

        public function __construct() {}

        public function __get($name) {
            if (in_array($name, $this->vars)) {
                return $this->vars[$name];
            }
        }

        public function __set($name, $value) {
            $this->vars[$name] = $value;
        }

        public function __call($method, $arguments) {
            .....
        }

        public function __callStatic($method, $arguments) {
            .....
        }
    }
?>
```

I can then use this object like:

```
<?php
    // Calles foo::__construct as normal
    $myFoo = new foo();

    // Calls the __set method parsing the values $name as "myVar1" and $value as "foo"
    $myFoo->myVar1 = "foo";
    // Runs the __set method parsing the values $name as "myVar2" and $value as "bar"
    $myFoo->myvar2 = "bar";

    // Calls the __get method parsing the value $name as "myVar1"
    // and then a seccond call to __get parsing $name as "myVar2"
    echo $myFoo->myVar1 . $myFoo->myVar2

    // Calls __call parsing $name as "foobar" and $values as null
    $myFoo->foobar();

    // Calls __callStatic parsing $name as "barfoo" and $values as null
    foo::barfoo();
?>
```

Can vb.net even cope with this basic level of programming or is it just not possible at all?

Comment: Regarding `get`and `set`this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20152225/5457643) might be helpful.

Comment: The `get` and `set` part is easy, just use a `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` or in a generic way `public class Magic(Of T) ... Dictionary(Of String, T)`. The `call` and `callStatic` could be done with [Reflection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206412/Reflection-An-Introduction-to-Reflection-in-NE).

Comment: The answer on the other post is not quite what I was asking for, I have updated my question to reflect this and add more detail.

Comment: @Turamarth @Alex-B I don't want to have to write `object.__get(name)` and `object.__set(name, value)` I want to be able to use `object.property` `object.property = value` to get and set the properties like PHP can.

Comment: This is not possible in VB. The closest you will get is via a default property and call `object("property")` and `object("property") = value`. Additionally, I don´t understand your last edit: When you call `$myFoo->foobar();` why must there be a function `__call` in foo? You could just create a function `foobar(ParamArray params String())` in vb and call via `foo.foobar()`.

Comment: @Alex-B when working at the most base level of any system you never know what the end developer is going to do. There are multiple reasons why you would not create a function and use __call or __callStatic instead. I seriously can not understand why any language would not have the ability to do this. It just adds another point to why Microsoft can not create a useful language. In my case. I need a class but I have no idea what properties this class is going to have at run time or what types those properties are going to be.

Comment: Since your last comment is full of subjectivity I´m out here. If you reuqire those specific php feature than use php or any other language which supports them. There are plenty (Ruby, Lisp, Lua, Python, ..)

Comment: I don't exactly understand the point of have a class that you don't know nothing about... That's why interfaces and abstract classes are made for, when you only know a part of the Object you will be working with...

Comment: @SuperPeanut Take for instance a generic JSON parser, I have no idea at run time what properties or the types of those properties are. But I need to create a generic class system to be able to handle the translation from a JSON string to a vb.net object. This is one reason why you would need to do this.

Comment: Then you can look out for JSON .Net... The idea is that you know that what arrives as a JSON string will match a class of your assembly, even if you don't know which one at run-time.

Comment: @SuperPeanut True and yes that would be used in that case, but to write JSON.net they would have had to write it like I was saying as they would not know what objects you would be using at run time.

Comment: No, they just explore the destination object's properties using reflection and map them to the JSON object's properties

Comment: My point exactly, they have no idea what properties said object has so they have to find it out some how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, this all resumes to : Is VB .Net a dynamic language ?

Answer is no.

then, what is the difference between a dynamic (like PHP) and a static (like VB .Net) language and which one is the best ?

[Here is an answer I found here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-a-dynamic-programming-language-and-a-static-programming-language-Which-one-is-better-or-in-other-words-has-a-better-prospect) :

> Neither is "better".   They optimize different variables.   Which variable you want to optimize depends on what you are trying to accomplish.
>
> All languages are designed to translate human-readable code into machine instructions.   A dynamic language (Lisp, Perl, Python, Ruby) is designed to optimize programmer efficiency, so you can implement functionality with less code.   A static language (C, C++, etc) is designed to optimize hardware efficiency, so that the code you write executes as quickly as possible.
>
> The key defining feature of a dynamic language is that entire language is available at all times.   This means you can execute code at compile-time, and compile code at execution time.   This, combined with other features (first class functions, introspection) enables Metaprogramming, programs that can modify themselves.   This lets a programmer do the same task with less work compared to a static language, and in some cases allows you to do things that simply can't be done AT ALL in a static language.   However, all this magic comes at the expense of execution speed.
>
> Static languages are not doing much (if any) behind-the-scenes magic, so there's much less overhead.   Because the compile phase and execution phase are completely decoupled, the compiler can run longer and generate better-optimized machine code.   For some tasks static code can be several orders of magnitude faster than a dynamic language.
>
> Both language types have their place.   Perl, Python, and Ruby are great languages for most everyday tasks -- but they are all themselves written in C.

Answer (score 0):

In short after a lengthy discussion, there is not way to do this in VB.net